# Kindle highlights not syncing between devices

Tags: kindle

I have the Kindle app on my iPhone and iPad. When I go into a book on the iPad and add a highlight I never see it appear on the same book on my iPhone, even if I press the sync item from the side menu on the iPhone.

Comment: Having the same problem with syncing highlights between Kindle iPhone app and Kindle Mac app. It's quite pathetic that Amazon can build the most advanced cloud infrastructure and speech recognition, but fails implementing a reliable sync mechanism for their own ebook ecosystem :(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by removing the book from my iPhone and redownloading it.

Now if I want to see highlights sync immediately between the devices I have to go to the Library after adding a highlight and then go to Library on the other device, press sync and go back into the book. Then a few seconds later the highlight appears. 
Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had highlights on an iPhone which were refusing to sync. Manually triggering a sync from within the Settings area and killing/restarting the app failed to fix it.

I restarted the iPhone (hold power and home until you see the silver, Apple logo appear) and then opened the Kindle app again.

I could see a lot of network activity (the icon was cycling next to the 4G symbol at the top) and then all of a sudden the highlights all synched and were visible on https://read.amazon.co.uk/notebook (also https://read.amazon.com/notebook ).

Answer (score 0):

Removing and adding (redownloading) the book on my Macbook fixed it also.

Answer (score 0):

Kindle might be the worst app I've ever seen. The great Amazon knows how to ruin their reputation with this little software. The best way to sync accross all devices is sync the device you did a lot of works on, delete the book on the target device to sync with, and then download the book again. This is the only solution working 100% I've found so far. I cannot believe how few the number of additional options other than highlights and notes are implemented on Kindle. There are billion users out there in the world and Amazon seems to ignore how much they are frustrated about this app.